# How to read in dependencies externally defined to the root package.json?

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

**I'm not sure what this would be called or referred to as.**

**If you know of the proper TERM to use or something for me to reference for learning how to I would appreciate the link.**

I'm looking at our projects package.json file which is rather large with all of the dependencies. The problem is that just by looking at the file you have no idea where these dependencies are being used within the application.

Is there a way to break it up? I'm looking for a way to structure the project.json file in a way where the dependencies are defined where they are used.
e.g. Let say we have this dependency listing which we'll say is 3 areas [CORE, CHARTS, MAP]

```
  "dependencies": {
    // CORE
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.1",
    "compodoc": "~0.0.41",
    // CHART
    "chart.js": "~2.9.4",
    // MAP
    "leaflet": "~1.7.1",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "~1.4.1",
    "leaflet-maskcanvas": "~1.0.0"
  }
```

Is it possible to move the CHART & MAP items to an external package.json file or something that defines the dependencies such as below e.g.?

```
  "dependencies": {
    // CORE
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.1",
    "compodoc": "~0.0.41",
    // CHART
    filepathToCHARTPackage.json,
    // MAP
    filepathToMAPPackage.json
  }
```

I'm wanting to do this because if the dependencies are defined within the components or subareas defined then it makes it much easier to maintain and cleanup features that are added or removed without orphaned references being left behind.

Answer (score 0):

Within your component folders you created, e.g. src/app/map-world

1. Create a package.json file just like the one used in the root of the application.
2. Specify the packages required for that component
3. In the root package.json file dependencies you reference the component package.json (see below)

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    ...,
    "map-world": "file:src/app/map-world/"
}
```

When you run npm install as you normally would, it will pick up the component specified package.json file and install the package dependencies within the root/node_modules folder and NOT the sub-component folder.

I'm still working on setting the images to a folder also within the new component rather than at the root without having to specify the full path from the root.